# CSS how to float item right or left respectively to the html direction?

Tags: css

I have an item that I want to place at 10% bottom and 5% right if the document is set on RTL and 5% left if the document is set on LTR - without making multiple versions of this CSS code, something like:

```
.some-item {
  bottom: 10%;
  last: 5%;
}
```

Is this possible that way? Any better approaches?

Comment: Please show your html code ? can you create a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: how do you set your document direction ?

Comment: `html dir="rtl"` or `html dir="ltr"` . Just a blank new html page with style tag, I ask about floating without mention the "right" and "left" keywords but some "modern" keyword..

Comment: Instead of `left` use `inline-start`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this:

```
 <div style="direction:rtl">Hello, world!</div>
 <div style="direction:ltr">Hello, world!</div>

 div[style*="direction:rtl"] {
   font-size: 72px;
}


 div[style*="direction:ltr"] {
   font-size: 12px;
 }
```

this code means that if the div has a style direction:rtl apply font-size=72px else font-size=12px.

You can use body instead of a div.
I hope this code will help you.